# How to find the best combination of two random parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

Sorry if this is a general question I'm a bit of a beginner and I'm looking for a simple and uncomplicated library or way to do the following

I have some code that eventually depends on two parameters eg:

```
param1 = 12
param2 = 5
```

and at the end I get a variable that changes depending on these parameters

```
score = 5031
```

I want an easy way to loop over the code with randomized parameters until it finds the combination that gives the highest score

Comment: Any reproducible code to debug maybe ?

Comment: there is always the random module ... not sure what  (if anything) your very vage code less question has to do with machine-learning or optimization. Did you read the tag-descriptions? Please read [ask] and provide a [mre].

Comment: You could use stochastic gradient descent or some other type of stochastic optimization function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get it by looping for every index in the list and choosing the max out of it with max built in function